# When serializing entity with [Column] attribute I get back null data

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have a Customer Entity which looks like this:

```
[Column("Customer_id")]
public int CustomerID { get; set; }
[Column("Customer_Name")]
public string CustomerName { get; set; }
[Column("Database_name")]
public string DatabaseName { get; set; }
```

I put the [Column] attribute in order to capitalize the props names. The problem is that when I try to serialize some data I receive in a SQL query to this entity, the data I get after the serialization is null because the serialization mechanism refers to the "inline" properties' names and not the ones I gave in the attributes.

My SQL query:

```
var query = "SELECT Customer_id, Customer_Name, Database_name FROM xxx";
return await context.Database.SqlQuery<Customer>(query).ToListAsync();
```

Anyone knows how can I solve it without removing the attributes?

Comment: Can you give ur table schema too

Answer (score 1):

In my SQL SELECT query I used "as.." and added names that correspond with the new names I gave in the [Column] attribute.
So now it look like this:

```
var query = "SELECT Customer_id as CustomerID, Customer_Name as CustomerName, Database_name as DatabaseName FROM xxx";
```

and now the serialization works fine!